# Why won't google search console accept my sitemap?

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I've recently deployed my first site and I've tried to create a sitemap.xml file so I can get my site indexed faster by google. I created the sitemap.xml and put it in the public directory of my react app, you can find the sitemap.xml file here https://theprofitladder.co.uk/sitemap.xml.

When I upload this sitemap.xml page file to google's search console, it gets rejected. Does anyone know why this is?

I've also made a basic sitemap page because I thought it might help SEO, you can find that here https://theprofitladder.co.uk/sitemap in case you need it.

Here is a screenshot of the sitemap area on google search console...
[image]

... and here is the rejection message I get on google search console

[image]

Is there something wrong with my robots.txt file maybe https://www.theprofitladder.co.uk/robots.txt

Comment: You shouldn't make a sitemap to help with SEO because they have very little to do with SEO.   A sitemap can help get Googlebot to come crawl all your pages, but it won't influence which pages might get indexed nor will it help rankings.   See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: Alternate example: https://vishvasa.github.io/vedAH_yajuH/sitemap.xml